# How to make laptop without an OS boot directly to an external monitor?

Tags: boot, laptop, operating-systems, external-display

My laptop screen broke so I've been looking up methods to boot a laptop directly to an external monitor and many people say to use the FN+F4, which I have tried and it has failed to produce any results... I'm thinking the fact that I don't have an OS is complicating it... Does anyone have any suggestions or know how to solve my problem?

("No" is a valid response)

Comment: what make / model laptop?

Comment: I didn't realize you commented :[]... It's an Hp pavillion dv4

Comment: Do you see the BIOS output on your external monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the laptop, connecting and powering on an external display and leaving the laptop lid itself closed can be enough to tell it to use the external display from boot.

Comment: I'd try that... if I hadn't ripped off the laptop monitor... Maybe I'll replace it...

Comment: You could try pressing down the lid sense switch with a small screwdriver or other thin object.

Comment: Indeed, I could... It sounds much better than my compulsive pressing of FN+F4

Answer (score 0):

You could [pxe boot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) it to get around the problem of not having an OS.  This may only work if your bios is already configured for it though.

[What is PXE (Preboot Execution Environment)](http://searchwinit.techtarget.com/definition/PXE)

Comment: "Will think about trying it" would be a better descriptor of my actions. Still thX

Comment: @Jenna :) np, good luck w/ your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Comment by [BlackTechHack](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0eJ79WKGzdb8ixo2MP7mRw) in [Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/xTFxwVxF_a8)

Basically, just disconnect the laptop screen from the motherboard (HP laptop has a sticker that says "LCD cable") and connect it to an external monitor using VGA, HDMI, or Display Port.